# What is the chord that contains C D♯ F♯ A♯ (C bass)?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, harmony

I figured it out by ear in several songs, looks like a dim chord but with a slightly higher last note but cannot put a name on it.

I'm calling it "dim+" for my personal notes, but I'd like to know the official name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [C half diminished 7](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-diminished_seventh_chord) chord:

[image]

The scale that typically pairs with this half diminished chord is the locrian scale. For example, C half diminished 7 (usually notated C min 7 ♭5 or Cø7) would be played with the C locrian scale:

[image]

The locrian mode is the seventh mode of the major scale, and thus C locrian has all the same notes as the D♭ major scale, as can be seen above. There are other scales that work with half diminished chord, but the locrian scale is a good start. C half diminished can resolve to D♭ maj, or it can be part of a "minor ii-V-i progression," such as Cø7 - F7♯9 - B♭ minor. There are other functions for this chord, but these are two big ones.

Answer (score 3):

That would likely be D♯m6, third inversion, with the notes as you've written them.

Or, if the tonic here is definitely C, it would be C1/2dim7, but the notes would be C E♭ G♭ B♭. Also known as the [Tristan chord](http://dictionary.onmusic.org/terms/3693-tristan_chord).

Comment: He's not spelling it any way really, is he.  Just fret-counting.   Though it's interesting to note that a half-dim7 (often written as m7b5)  has the same pitches as a m6 chord.  (That's a minor triad plus a major 6th, not a major triad plus a minor 6th.  Don't argue, that's just the slightly illogical way it's named.)

Answer (score 2):

It's a C half diminished 7th chord. I often spell it as C-E♭-G♭-B♭, but your spelling at least gets the notes right.

Answer (score 0):

In jazz chord/scale theory, this chord is a C half-diminished chord, and is the sixth mode of E♭ jazz minor (melodic minor ascending and descending), the scale itself being called the half-diminished scale.

Answer (score -3):

It is C #6sus#2#4no5

I identify chords with my brain

Comment: Do you think this is a better answer than "C half-diminished seventh"?

Comment: Yes, I know how to identify chords with my brain

Comment: I'm fascinated. Exactly *how* do you do this?

Comment: I think about what is the chord

Comment: since the time I asked the question, I have taken jazz lessons and it's definitely half-diminished, not C#6 whatever.